# Does aptana save my files on every keypress?

Tags: aptana

I've just downloaded Aptana to do some web-development. I've downloaded the JsTestDriver plugin (javascript testing framework) which works fantastic, however there is one thing bugging me... In my run configuration of JsTestDriver i set it to run everytime i save my project. The funny thing is that the my run configuration is executed everytime i press a key... Does this mean that aptana saves my project everytime i make a single change to it? If so, how do I disable it? Running all my unit tests everytime i press a single key is kinda taxing on my system :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Disable "Build Automatically" in Eclipse -> Workspace settings